# Is it possible to encrypt a user’s email in a zero-knowledge way and still send them emails?

Tags: encryption, database

This is kind of hypothetical, but let’s say I have a web app and I want to store a user’s email for sending notifications to.

Is there any zero-knowledge way to hide their email from ourselves and any potential database leaks while still having the ability to send to their address (which would obviously require the email plaintext?)

Alternatively, if there probably isn’t a way to hide it from ourselves is there any way to obfuscate the address in the database but still the user emails?

Comment: [Relevant but probably not a duplicate](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/66569/23623)

Comment: To send an email you must have that email address in plaintext at some point.  What you could do is assign the user some sort of unique ID and then have a service that could send an email to that ID to separate the email address from the user's other data, but that seems like overkill to me.